# too few arguments in function call?

Tags: c++, class, declaration, member-functions

too few arguments in function call? what's wrong with this code?
I want to output to std::cout day

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Date
{
public:
    Date(unsigned _day, unsigned _month, unsigned _year) : day(_day), month(_month), year(_year) {}
    int GetDate(Date& dt)
    {
        return dt.day;
    }
private:
    unsigned day, month, year;
};

int main()
{
    Date dt(07, 10, 2004);
    std::cout << dt.GetDate();

    return 0;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

i understand the principle but I don't know what to do

```
/*too few arguments in function call
    Error   C2660   'Date::GetDate': function does not take 0 arguments */
```

Comment: Unlike python, in C++ this (self in python) is _implicitly_ passed to non-static member function. You should define `int GetDate()` and simply return `day`.

Comment: Unrelated to the error, you should make `GetDate` const to be able to call it on const objects: `int GetDate() const {...}` (since it doesn't modify any fields).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this member function

```
int GetDate(Date& dt)
{
    return dt.day;
}
```

is a non-static member function then it is natural when it outputs the data member day of the object for which it is called. But it is defined with a parameter that accepts another object of the type `Date`.

Thus in this call of the function

```
std::cout << dt.GetDate();
```

you need to specify an argument of the type `Date` like for example

```
Date dt(07, 10, 2004);
std::cout << dt.GetDate( dt );
```

But this does not make a great sense.

The function should be defined in the class like

```
int & GetDate()
{
    return day;
}
```

with its overload

```
const int & GetDate() const
{
    return day;
}
```

In this case this code snippet

```
Date dt(07, 10, 2004);
std::cout << dt.GetDate();
```

will make a sense.

Though it would be better to name the function as `GetDay`.

Pay attention that this statement

```
std::cin.get();
```

does not have an effect because it is placed after the return statement. Maybe you mean

```
std::cin.get();
return 0;
```

Comment: const int & GetDate() const {}    I don't understand this

Comment: @SamuelRobb Such a function can be called for a constant object of the type Date. For example if you will declare const Date dt(07, 10, 2004); then you may call only the constant member function GetDate. Otherwise the compiler will issue an error if you will try to call the non-constant member function.

Comment: const int & GetDate() const {} here i'm confused by the const at const int and the ref

Comment: @SamuelRobb Without the referenced return type the function will return a copy of the data member day. But usually you need the original object for example to use it in a container.

Comment: Until you change the internal implementation and then you have no int to reference anymore... Do return a copy.

Answer (score 2):

You have defined `GetDate()` as a non-static method of the `Date` class, and have it take in an explicit `Date&` object reference as a parameter.  But `main()` is not passing in a `Date` object into that parameter, hence the error.

There is no need to pass in the object explicitly.  As a non-static method, `GetDate()` has a hidden `this` parameter that refers to the `Date` object that `GetDate()` is called on.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Date
{
public:
    Date(unsigned _day, unsigned _month, unsigned _year) : day(_day), month(_month), year(_year) {}
    int GetDate() const
    {
        return day; // this->day
    }
private:
    unsigned day, month, year;
};

int main()
{
    Date dt(07, 10, 2004);
    std::cout << dt.GetDate();

    return 0;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: do all member functions have a hidden this->?

Comment: @SamuelRobb **non-static** member functions do, yes

Comment: All non-static member functions have a `this`. Handy reading (also explains why the `const` was added): https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions . Since there are non-static member functions, here's some reading on [static  member functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static#Static_member_functions). Most notably they have no `this` and thus don't need an object to be called.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should update the implementation of your `GetDate` function.

```
int GetDate()
{
   return day;
}
```

Comment: Rational for this: `GetDate` is a member function. There is no need to pass in a `Date` instance because the function is invoked on a `Date` and can access the members of that `Date`.

Comment: why can't I access using the parameter?

Comment: If you access with a parameter, you need to provide the parameter: `std::cout << dt.GetDate(dt);`. See how you have two `dt`s? You only really want to have one `dt`. Either you make the function a static member and pass in `dt` or you leave it a non-static member and invoke it on `dt`. There is no need to do both.

Answer (score -2):

The function GetDate has a parameter, that you are not passing in the function main.

It should be

```
Date a(1,1,2001); 

std::cout << dt.GetDate(a);
```

Comment: And what would `a` be used for inside `GetDate`? Does it make sense to invoke `getDate` on one `Date` instance to return the `day` of a wholly different `Date`? Doe sit makes sense to pass in a different `Date` and then not use that `Date`?

Comment: I know the code does not make sense, but he was asking about the compilation error. The compilation error is caused by the lack of an argument in the call. I could ask why a function called GetDate return just the day.

Comment: When the code does something that does not make sense, prefer to write an answer that makes the code make the maximum amount of sense. That would be to remove the unused parameter from the function and explain how the parameter caused the problem and why it wasn't necessary in the first place. Here you've chosen to suggest doing something just as nonsensical and now the asker has two problems in their code instead of a compiler error. If the question makes too little sense to make a sensible answer, you ask for clarification and vote to close the question, if you have the ability to do so.